# what is the difference between CanvasBitmap and CanvasVirtualBitmap in Win2d?

Tags: uwp, win2d

what is the difference between CanvasBitmap and CanvasVirtualBitmap in Win2d?Which is efficient to use?And How they are differ from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description in the [document](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasVirtualBitmap.htm):

> `CanvasVirtualBitmap` can be used to load and draw images that are larger than the maximum size of bitmaps supported on this device. `CanvasDevice.MaximumBitmapSizeInPixels` can be used to determine this size. Generally, you can assume that this value is at least 4096. Any attempt to load a `CanvasBitmap` larger than the maximum bitmap size will fail. `CanvasVirtualBitmap` allows you to reliably load any sized image.

This explains the difference between `CanvasVirtualBitmap` and `CanvasBitmap`.

`CanvasBitmap` is used to load a bitmap of a certain size and can be loaded by the current device. But for images of uncertain size that may exceed the current device rendering range, you can use `CanvasVirtualBitmap`.

Thanks.